# counting number of rows with specific text and extracting rows from positive hits

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a text file and I want to count the number of times a line has specific text. The first line of text is written on 5 columns and the other line of text on 6 columns:

The 5-column line:

```
***** No hits found *****
```

the 6-column line:

```
Sequences producing significant alignments: (Bits) Value
```

I would also like to extract information the positive hits for the 6-column line. That is, on a given line where the text above is found (Sequences producing..), I want to extract the text from two lines below (~10 columns) and 6 lines above (9 columns) this line. The line 6 lines above the positive hit (i.e. (Sequences producing..) begins with

```
Query=
```

Although the line 2 lines below the hit varies.

First answer:

```
grep -c "string" infile
```

The second question is a bit more complicated

Comment: Have you looked at the -A and -B flags for grep? They grab context lines around your match. It looks like your second answer is grep -B6 -A2 'Sequences producing'

Comment: It would probably help if you showed an example of your input file. I assume you're parsing BLAST output, so please show us an example and the output you would want to see from that example.

Comment: Always remember that a picture is worth a 1000 words. So an input/output sample would have been the way to go here.

Comment: Do what Jeremy said regarding the -A and -B flags for grep: `grep -A2 -B6 'Sequences producing' filename` and either pipe it through `nl` for line numbers or `wc -l` for amount of lines.

    `grep -A2 -B6 'Sequences producing' $filename | wc -l` 
will show number of 'hits'

    `grep -A2 -B6 'Sequences producing' $filename | nl`
will show each "hit" with a line number in front of it.